# Shaded area and curved arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I drew a map which sends everything in the domain apart from i to a fixed point r and sends i to 2. However, I couldn't make curved arrows as well as shaded area as appears in the attachment below. Could you please help me. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% <-- added, 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  >=stealth,
  x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm }
  }% end of tikzset


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]

 \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}, left=-1.7cm] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

  \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 2/\scriptstyle2}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$},left=-1.7cm] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x/\label in {8/\scriptstyle i}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

  \foreach \x/\label in {10/\scriptstyle r}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$}] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    \foreach \x/\label in {16/\scriptstyle n}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}, right=.0cm] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

    \foreach \x/\label in {16/\scriptstyle n}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$},right=.0cm] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};
  %********************************************
\path[draw,  dotted] (t8) edge (t16);
\path[draw,  dotted] (t0) edge (t8);
    %*****************************************
  \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t0) -- (b10);
  \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t8) -- (b2);
   \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t16) -- (b10);
   %******************************************
    \node[left] at (3,0) {$\sigma=$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfil

   \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only focus on the "fill between curved arrows" part in my answer. You can conveniently draw such arrows with the `to[in=x,out=y]` syntax, where `x` and `y` are the impact and outgoing angles. (In addition, there is a `looseness` parameter, but that's maybe not needed here.) This allows you to draw the arrows, and to define the path bounding the area that is to be filled. One has to be a bit careful because nodes are extended objects. So I added

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \path[fill=red!20]  (t0) to[out=-45,in=135] (b10.135)--(b10.45) to[out=45,in=-135] (t16) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
```

to your code, which requires the `backgrounds` library, since presumably you want the filling on the background. The `(b10.135)--(b10.45)` bit is because the `b10` node is an extended object.

[image]

That's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  >=stealth,
  x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm }
  }% end of tikzset


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]
\foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}, left=-1.7cm] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

\foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 2/\scriptstyle2}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$},left=-1.7cm] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x/\label in {8/\scriptstyle i}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

  \foreach \x/\label in {10/\scriptstyle r}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$}] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    \foreach \x/\label in {16/\scriptstyle n}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}, right=.0cm] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

    \foreach \x/\label in {16/\scriptstyle n}
  \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$},right=.0cm] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};
%********************************************
\path[draw,  dotted] (t8) edge (t16);
\path[draw,  dotted] (t0) edge (t8);
%*****************************************
\draw[uuuuuu,->] (t0) to[out=-45,in=135] (b10);
\draw[uuuuuu,->] (t8) to[out=-90,in=90] (b2);
\draw[uuuuuu,->] (t16) to[out=-135,in=45] (b10);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill=red!20]  (t0) to[out=-45,in=135] (b10.135)--(b10.45) to[out=45,in=-135] (t16) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
%******************************************
\node[left] at (3,0) {$\sigma=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Marmot! thanks a lot. I don't even know how to express my appreciation to YOU in words.